# Summation of matrix multiplications of three matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a formula as below

$$\vec{H}=A_1\Omega \vec{V}_1+A_2\Omega \vec{V}_2+A_3\Omega \vec{V}_3$$

where $A_1$, $A_2$ and $A_3$ are matrices of size $3 \times 3$;
      $\vec{V}_1$, $\vec{V}_2$, $\vec{V}_3$ and $\vec{H}$ are vectors of size $3 \times 1$;
      $\Omega$ is a **symmetric** matrix of size $3 \times 3$ . More specifically, $\Omega=\vec{k} \ \vec{k}^T$ where $\vec{k}$ is a  vector of size $3 \times 1$.

**My question is:** Is there any way to combine those 3 terms into 1 term (simplifying the formula of H)?  For example, something like $\vec{H}=P \Omega \vec{Q}$. Other forms are OK, as long as only one term remains on the right side.

**What I have tried:**

- I have tried to expand all the elements of the terms in the right side both manually and using Matlab symbolic calculation. But I couldn't return it as a matrix multiplication of $\Omega$ and other matrices
- Since my knowledge about matrix calculation is poor. I have been reading about it quite a while, but again, I couldn't figure out if the simplification in this case would be possible and how.

Therefore, I have decided to come here to ask. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mean something like $H=A\Omega V$, where $A=[A_1,A_2,A_3]$ and $V=\begin{bmatrix}V_1\\V_2\\V_3\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Hi Algebraic Pavel, no, what I meant was $A_1$, $A_2$ and $A_3$ are three matrices of size 3x3. And I need to simplify the sum of the 3 terms above to become just one term if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution：
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\vec{H} &=& A_1 \Omega \vec{V_1} + A_2 \Omega \vec{V_2} + A_3 \Omega \vec{V_3}\\  
&=&A_1 \vec{k}\vec{k}^T \vec{V_1} + A_2 \vec{k}\vec{k}^T \vec{V_2} + A_3 \vec{k}\vec{k}^T \vec{V_3}   \quad  &(\Omega=\vec{k}\vec{k}^T) \\ 
&=&\vec{k}^T \vec{V_1}A_1 \vec{k} + \vec{k}^T \vec{V_2}A_2 \vec{k} + \vec{k}^T \vec{V_3}A_3 \vec{k} &(\vec{k}^T \vec{V_i}\text{ is a number}) \\
&=&\left(\vec{k}^T\vec{V_1}A_1+\vec{k}^T\vec{V_2}A_2+\vec{k}^T\vec{V_3}A_3 \right)\vec{k} 
&(\text{extract the common factor } \vec{k} ) \\
&\not=&\vec{k}^T \left( \vec{V_1}A_1+\vec{V_2}A_2+\vec{V_3}A_3 \right)\vec{k} 
&\text{(since $\vec{V_i}$'s size is $3 \times 1$, $A_i$'s size is $3 \times 3$, $\vec{V_i} A_i$ is undefined)}
 \end{eqnarray}$$

Sorry for the previous wrong answer.

Comment: Hi robit, it seems like the matrix multiplications of the 3 terms inside the brackets are undefined as $\vec{V}$ has the size of 3x1 while A is 3x3. Therefore, the terms inside the brackets can not be combined, is it right?

Comment: You're right. $\vec{V}A$ is undefined, so the best answer I can obtain is $\vec{H}=\left(\vec{k}^T\vec{V_1}A_1 + \vec{k}^T\vec{V_2}A_2 + \vec{k}^T\vec{V_3}A_3 \right)\vec{k}$ .